# C# merging two or more objects

Tags: c#

Hi I want to merge two objects together so that i can use the merged object to do something else.it's actually a simple airport program, i have "Route" and ""Flight" and if i want to add getting ticket i need each flight to be on a route if you know what i mean.but notice that i don't want to compare them.and i have an array of objects for each of them if it helps.

```
 IRoute R = new LocalRoute(port, destination, routenum);
 IFlight F = new LocalFlight(time, date,capacity);
```

Comment: It sounds like you just need to create a type with both of those as properties. (I would personally have expected a flight to know its route, mind you - is there any reason it doesn't?)

Comment: well that's what i want,a flight should know its route but how?

Comment: Best way would be to create new class with properties of type of those two objects. You could then add a constructor which accepts all the parameters for both of the objects so you could initialize those in one call.

Comment: Add a property to `LocalFlight` that is of `LocalRoute` type.

Comment: You should consider your class structure. Ticket(`*`) -> (1) Flight (`*`) -> Route(1).

Comment: If you can't edit the existing classes, maybe you can make use of the Tuple datastructure (Requires .NET 4.0 or greater). Some info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: I can't use Tuple because what if i have 100 items?in this case i don't even know how many items i will have!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give the `Flight` objects a `Route` property.  This makes more sense to me than creating a class to hold both a Flight and a Route, since in the real world a flight should know which route it has to take.

For example:

```
public class Route {
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public string Port { get; private set; }

    public string Destination { get; private set; }

    public Route(int number, string port, string destination) {
        Number = number;
        Port = port;
        Destination = destination;
    }
}

public class Flight {
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; private set; }

    public int Capacity { get; private set; }

    public Route Route { get; private set; }

    public Flight(DateTime departureTime, int capacity, Route route) {
        DepartureTime = departureTime;
        Capacity = capacity;
        Route = route;
    }
}
```

Then you can have a list of possible routes and a list of flights, each of which has a reference to a route.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do what you are looking for?

```
public class FlightDetails
{
    IRoute Route {get;set}
    IFlight Flight {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more clear picture you can do something like this

```
public class FlightDetails
{
IRoute Route {get;set}
IFlight Flight {get;set;}

public FlightDetails(IRoute r,IFlight f)
 {
   this.Route = r;this.Flight = f;
 }
}

IRoute R = new LocalRoute(port, destination, routenum);
IFlight F = new LocalFlight(time, date,capacity);

 FlightDetails Fd = new FlightDetails(R,F);
```